# Extracting Values from XM using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, xmltocsv

I have a XM tag as
<Address_Line_Data Label="Address Line 1" Type="ADDRESS_LINE_1">Noida</Address_Line_Data>
<Address_Line_Data Label="Address Line 2" Type="ADDRESS_LINE_2">UP<Address_Line_Data>

I need to get the value as
Address_1 = Noida
Address_2 = UP

this i am doing it in Python using xml.etree.ElementTree

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show us what you have tried so far. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please load a VALID xml document  (the current one is not valid) and the code you wrote so far. Explain what is the problem.